# Does django models.ImageField cache the image file before saving?

Tags: python, django, caching

I know is a silly question , but i am using django with django-dropbox storage.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', storage=STORAGE, null=True, blank=True)
    thumb = models.ImageField(upload_to='thumbs', storage=STORAGE, null=True, blank=True)
    url = models.TextField(max_length=150, default = 'url')
```

When I access the django admin and I upload one image file and hit the save button , I want to make an thumbnail with the same image and also save it.
I can make it work like this:

```
def save(self):
    # create a thumbnail
    #self.create_thumbnail()
    super(Product, self).save()
    url = self.image.url[26:-5]
    self.url = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/"+url
    super(Product, self).save()
    #and run the create_thumbnail_function()
    #who will download the file from dropbox and then resize it
    #and save another time the product model
    #super(Product, self).save()
```

But this means a lot of traffic for the server and will delay on saving.
Should I firstly upload the image to server , and then manipulate the image and save it to dropbox?
**Or is there any posibility to use the cached image(if django does this), manipulate it and then save it to dropbox?**
**If this is possible , I would like to get the path of the cached Image.**
Thank you , and sorry for my english.
Any help will be apreciated